# Unable to create zip files with shell.application

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

The following example doesn't seem to work on my Windows Server 2008 SP2 nor my Windows 7 Pro Sp1.

Command:

```
$shellapp = new-object -com shell.application
$shellapp
```

Output:

```
Application         Parent
-----------         ------
System.__ComObject  System.__ComObject
```

Command:

```
$zipfile = $shellapp.namespace("c:\temp\file.zip")
$zipfile
```

Output: No output?  (I'm assuming it didn't work and $zipfile is null)

Command:

```
$zipfile.copyhere("c:\temp\file.txt")
```

Output:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:18
+ $zipfile.copyhere <<<< ("file.txt")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (copyhere:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I've tried to re-associate `.Zip` with the instructions: [How to restore Windows default Zip file functionality?](https://superuser.com/questions/35503/how-to-restore-windows-default-zip-file-functionality).

I've also tried to re-register with `regsvr32.dll zipfldr.dll` with no success.

Comment: Where did you get the example from?

Comment: There are quite a few [Questions about using zipping and powershell here on serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/search?q=powershell+zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not creating a new zip file.  This is adding files to an existing zip file.  In your example, C:\temp\file.zip must already exist.

edit:

```
function New-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)
    set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false
}
```

Comment: So how do I create a zip file using powershell and built-in functionality only?

Comment: Edited my post.  Like that.